# Unable to update: failed to refresh cache:E:The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-shell-extensions/ppa/Ubuntu disco release'

Tags: updates, ppa

I am using Ubuntu 19.04 and getting this error.

[image: Error]

How to fix this?

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: Try this then `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:gnome-shell-extensions/ppa` followed by `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: @Tanny The linked duplicate that Jim posted should be the same case as yours. The custom repository you are using does not support Disco (19.04), at least not yet. You can verify this here: https://launchpad.net/~gnome-shell-extensions/+archive/ubuntu/ppa. Edit into your post what you have tried exactly please, so we can help you further.

Comment: @Jim i did as u said and its working.Thank you and to all